# Insert trigger for a spesific column

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. When I insert a new value for a spesific column I want to update another column in the second table. How I can do that?

Here is a simple example but it gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Insert'." error as expected.

```
Create trigger trigger_Insert_Months
on [Quantities]
after Insert
As 
if Insert([Work Name])
begin
    declare @NewWorkName varchar(200)
    select @NewWorkName = [Work Name] from inserted
    insert into [April]([Work Name])
    values (@NewWorkName)
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_Insert_Months
ON [Quantities]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [April]([Work Name])
    SELECT [Work Name] from inserted
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Quantities] WHERE [Quantities].[Work Name] = INSERTED.[Work Name] AND INSERTED.PrimaryKey != [Quantities].[PrimaryKey])
End
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_Insert_Months, Line 43
The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.Work Name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_Insert_Months, Line 43
The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.PrimaryKey" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_Insert_Months, Line 43
Invalid column name 'PrimaryKey'.

Comment: Can you show your table definitions for `Quantities` and `April`. By `PrimaryKey` I meant you will have to replace this with the name of the primary key column in the `Quantities` table.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. You want to insert values in table1 and update values in table2 with the inserted values.

```
create trigger tr1 on Table1
for insert 
as
begin
if exists (select 1 from inserted)
begin
update a
set a.col1 = b.col
from table2 as a
inner join (select * from inserted) as b
on a.id = b.id
end
end
```

This code activates the trigger when an insert happens in Table1 and updates Values of table2 of col1 with the inserted rows.
Change the ID column with the column having primary key in table2 and table1 and col1 with the column to be updated in table2